# Concerned about the outcome of insulation fibers

Tags: insulation

I was working in an attic ,an exhaust fan was turned on I immiedetly breathed and was choked with the insulation to the point I couldn't breath ,I now feel it in my lungs as uncomfortable ,any idea if fibers might have lodged in my lungs and what dangers I might encounter?

Answer (score 1):

No likely permanent danger, the effect is most likely limited to the acute irritation you are experiencing. Even if it contained some amount of a hazardous substance, a short term exposure is not likely to pose a long term health issue. Now if it happened to you *every day* during the course of your work, that would be a different story.